# How can I fetch photos from nextGen gallery in my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I am using NextGen Gallery in my Wordpress site, and I want to fetch images from nextGen Gallery as carousal in my index page. I am using following shortcode for this solution. But this does not work and shows that gallery not found.

I am applying this code

```
do_shortcode('[scrollGallery id=2 start=5 autoScroll=true thumbsdown=true]');
```

Answer (score 2):

You are applying the wrong parameter for the nextgen gallery. to import galleries using the nextgen gallery shortcode you need to use the following parameter "ngg_images".

so to pull up your gallery with the gallery id of 2 you would do the following

```
echo do_shortcode('[ngg_images gallery_ids="2" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_basic_slideshow" gallery_width="600" gallery_height="400"]');
```

Here is a link to the nextgen gallery website which explains all of the available parameter options.
http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/nextgen-gallery-shortcodes/